# How can I get the checkbox control inside the cell of the handsontable

Tags: checkbox, handsontable

I use a handsontable with a checkbox column, how could I get the checkbox control from the api ?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation [(DOC)](https://docs.handsontable.com/pro/1.7.0/demo-checkbox.html), you can see how to use checkbox, to change value just set true or false to the cell value with *setDataAtCell()*.

Good luck ;)